# Poco FIFOBuffer read() error

Tags: c++, sockets, poco-libraries

I am having trouble getting Poco::FIFOBuffer.read() to work. Either getting  access violation errors or stack around the variable result was corrupted.

```
    std::string output;

    Poco::FIFOBuffer recvData(BUFFERLEN);

    int iResult = mySockets[vect[2]]->receiveBytes(recvData);
    char* result = "";

    std::cout << recvData.read(result, recvData.size());
    output = result;
```

elswhere in the program a very similar thing seems to work fine (vect is a vector ) mySockets is a Map

```
Poco::FIFOBuffer sendData(BUFFERLEN, false);
sendData.copy(vect[3].c_str(), vect[3].size());
int iResult = mySockets[vect[2]]->sendBytes(sendData);
output = "data sent, sendBytes returned: " + std::to_string(iResult);
```

reference:http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.0/Poco.BasicFIFOBuffer.html#11400

Comment: `char* result = "";    std::cout << recvData.read(result, recvData.size());` You are attempting to change the contents of a string literal.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, your link to the `read` function says that the buffer is resized.  I'm sorry, but I can't see how that function can resize that buffer and have those changes reflect back to the caller if it is only passed a pointer to the buffer.  To resize a buffer then you either need a reference to a pointer, or a pointer to a pointer as the first parameter.  However that link only shows a pointer to T.  Either those docs are wrong, or there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Documentation is [wrong](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/869). Will be fixed in 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, the documentation is [wrong](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/869).

If you want the buffer to be automatically resized use [`Poco::Buffer<char>`](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Buffer.h#L33); alternatively, make sure that the `char*` points to enough space to accommodate the data (which is tricky - you'll have to query the FIFOBuffer to find out how much did `receiveBytes()` call return, so using `Poco::Buffer` is an easier option).